# SpriteKit Swift: SKView returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm making a game using spritekit. I'm using a joystick in my game which is declared in a separate SKNode class called 'joystick'.

In this class, I add a UIGesturerecongiser to the view from the class. In the constructor method, one of the parameters is a SKView which is passed from the game scene.

**Constructor Method in Joystick class:**

```
 init(colour: UIColor, position: CGPoint, skView: SKView) {
    //constructor method
    self.colour = colour;
    self.parentposition = position;
    self.view = skView;

    super.init();

    //setup properties
    //user interaction is needed to allow touches to be detected
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    //setup
    setup();
}
```

In the games scene, I initialise the class like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

     func setupJoyStick() {
        let joystick1 = Joystick(colour: UIColor.red, position: CGPoint(x: screenwidth / 3, y: screenwidth / 10 * 1.5), skView: self.view!)
        self.addChild(joystick1)
    }
}
```

**Error:**

When I run my app, I get an error because the 'self.view' return nil and because it is forced to unwrap, it causes a fatal error.

**Where View is defined:**

```
if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

        // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
        if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {

            // Copy gameplay related content over to the scene
            sceneNode.entities = scene.entities
            sceneNode.graphs = scene.graphs

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            sceneNode.size = view.bounds.size
            // Present the scene
            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

                view.presentScene(sceneNode)

                view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                view.showsFPS = true
                view.showsNodeCount = true
            }
        }
    }
```

**Additional Info:**

I'm using:

- Xcode 9.2
- Swift 4
- Sprite Kit

I'm testing it on:

- Iphone 6s
- Latest version of IOS (non-beta), latest public release.

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share code where you call `Joystick` init and where you store `self.view`?

Comment: So far you showed all the code irrelevant to the question, the joystick initializer does not matter since it is not even reached, you need to show the core from where you call it, and its context.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to get `view` property of `SKScene` but it's nil. It's because you didn't presented `SKScene`.

Unfortunately I haven't worked with `SpriteKit` but you can find info about `view` property [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519726-view) and about `SKScene` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene).